# Cerrar cuadro de diálogo al dar click en botón guardar

Tags: reactjs

Estoy utilizando componentes funcionales en mi aplicación, inicialmente tenía un componente y lo divide en 3 para poder tener mejor organizado el código y tener componentes reutilizables, el primero contiene una tabla, el segundo un `<dialog>` y el tercero un `<form>`.

En el componente donde se encuentra la tabla importe el `<dialog>`, dentro del componente `<dialog>` importe el formulario, de ese modo  el formulario está dentro del cuadro de diálogo y ese cuadro de diálogo se manda llamar desde user.

El objetivo es guardar una nueva suscripción y si lo hace el problema es que no se cierra el cuadro de diálogo al momento de dar click en **Add**

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el cuadro de diálogo se cierre al dar click en Add?

Tabla

```
export default function User(){ 

const[user, setUser]= useState({Users:[]});

 useEffect(()=>{
    const getUser=async()=>{
            const response =await axios.get('/api/users');
            setUser(response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
    }
    getUser();
},[]);

return(
<div>
<Dialogs/>
            <MaterialTable
            title="Users"
            columns={[
                  { title: 'Code', field: 'code' , type: 'numeric'},
                  { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
                  { title: 'Lastname', field: 'lastname' },
                  { title: 'Age', field: 'age', type: 'numeric'},
            ]}
            data={user.Users}
          />

  </div>
        );
        }
```

Dialog

```
function Dialogs(){
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
    return(
        <div>
                      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                      <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscription></DialogTitle>
                          <DialogContent>
                              <DialogContentText>
                                  Subscription
                              </DialogContentText>
                    <AddSuscription/>
                          </DialogContent>
                      <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                          Cancel
                        </Button>
                      </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Dialogs;
```

Form

```
export default function AddSuscription(props){

    const initialState={code:0, email:'', alias:''}

    const[subscription, setSubscription]=useState(initialState);

    const handleChange=(event)=>{
        setSubscription({...subscription,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    const handleSubmit=(event)=>{

        event.preventDefault();

        if(!subscription.code || !subscription.email || !subscription.alias) 
            return
                const postSubscription=async()=>{
                    try {
                        axios.post('/api/Subscription/add',subscription);
                        props.history.push('/Subscription'); 
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        console.log('error', error);
                    }
                }
                postSubscription();
    } 
return(
<div> 
                                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                                      <TextField
                                          id="filled-name"
                                          name="code"
                                          label="Code"
                                          value={subscription.code}
                                          onChange={handleChange}
                                          margin="normal"
                                      />
                                      <TextField
                                          id="filled-name"
                                          label="Email"
                                          value={subscription.email}
                                          name="email"
                                          onChange={handleChange}
                                          margin="normal"
                                      />
                                      <TextField
                                          id="filled-multiline-static"
                                          label="Alias"
                                          value={subscription.alias}
                                          name="alias"
                                          onChange={handleChange}
                                          margin="normal"
                                      />
                                      <Button
                                          variant="contained"
                                          color="primary"
                                          type="submit">
                                          Add
                                      </Button>
                                  </form>
<div> 
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es mandarle atraves de una propiedad una función para que puedas cerrar el dialogo desde el componente `AddSuscription`, eso debes mandarlo desde el componente `Dialogs` que es el que controla los botones de abrir y cerrar, puse el ejemplo mandandole la propiedad toggle `<AddSuscription toggle={handleClose} />` para luego en el `AddSuscription` usarla en el botón `Add` así `props.toggle()`

Dialog

```
function Dialogs(){
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
      setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
    };
    return(
        <div>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscription></DialogTitle>
                    <DialogContent>
                        <DialogContentText>
                            Subscription
                        </DialogContentText>
                        <AddSuscription toggle={handleClose} />
                    </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Dialogs;
```

Form

```
export default function AddSuscription(props){

    const initialState={code:0, email:'', alias:''}

    const[subscription, setSubscription]=useState(initialState);

    const handleChange=(event)=>{
        setSubscription({...subscription,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    const handleSubmit=(event)=>{

        event.preventDefault();

        if(!subscription.code || !subscription.email || !subscription.alias) 
            return
                const postSubscription=async()=>{
                    try {
                        axios.post('/api/Subscription/add',subscription);
                        props.history.push('/Subscription'); 
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        console.log('error', error);
                    }
                }
        postSubscription();

        if(props.toggle){
            props.toggle()
        }
    } 

    return(
        <div> 
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <TextField
                    id="filled-name"
                    name="code"
                    label="Code"
                    value={subscription.code}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                />
                <TextField
                    id="filled-name"
                    label="Email"
                    value={subscription.email}
                    name="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                />
                <TextField
                    id="filled-multiline-static"
                    label="Alias"
                    value={subscription.alias}
                    name="alias"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    margin="normal"
                />
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit">
                    Add
                </Button>
            </form>
        <div> 
    );
}
```

Comment: Gracias eso resolvio mi problema, solo una duda toggle es palabra reservada o se pudo haber sido cualquier palabra?

Comment: pudo haber sido el nombre que tu hubieras querido ponerle a la función que se encarga de cerrar el modal, toggle simplemente es la forma como yo acostumbro a llamarle por ser intuitivo